# Number of features used by PAM?

Tags: r, classification

I'm trying to use PAM as a classifier but I couldn't find a way to find how many genes are being used. Here is the code:

```
install.packages("plsgenomics")
library("plsgenomics")
library("pamr")
data(Colon)
data<-t(Colon$X)
rownames(data)<-Colon$gene.names
grp<-Colon$Y
grp = as.factor(grp)
tr.data = list(x = data, y = grp)
tr.train = pamr.train(tr.data)
new.scales <- pamr.adaptthresh(tr.train)
tr.train2 <- pamr.train(tr.data, threshold.scale=new.scales,prior = c(0.5,0.5))


  tr.train2
  Call:
  pamr.train(data = tr.data, threshold.scale = new.scales, prior = c(0.5, 
0.5))
  threshold nonzero errors
1  0.000     2000    18    
2  0.189     1490    13    
3  0.379     1128    11    
..........................

28 5.112        1    9     
29 5.301        1    9     
30 5.490        0    40    

 > new.scales
        1        2 
 1.000000 2.867972
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: there is no need to know about data. I'm just asking these are results and how can I learn about feature size used by pamr

Comment: This is a particular implementation of PAM in R. To access aspects of it, eg feature size, you would need special code in R. This is a perfectly reasonable question, & can be answered, but it needs a reproducible example to do so. Please add one.

Comment: I added the reproducible example, still no answer..

Comment: Thanks, @BenDuo. This should be on topic on [SO] now. I flagged it for the moderators to migrate it.